# c++ data structure to hold 128 bits of data

Tags: c++, data-structures, bit-manipulation

I need a data structure to hold some 120 bits of data.

I have bit manipulations like **type** var = 0X01000000000000000000000000000000) >> 120

What is the best data structure to hold such a lengthy data?

Comment: Refer this link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cpp_standard_library/bitset.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you specify what exactly you'd like to to with those bits, [`std::bitset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/) is probably your best bet.

Additionally, gcc and clang support [`unsigned __int128`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) on some targets. Though, this is non-standard.

Comment: I need to left shift , right shift . for e.g value = 0X01000000000000000000000000000000) >> 120 and store it that variable

Comment: @Prakrithi if that's all, then `std::bitset` will do fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset). It has operators `operator<<`, [`operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_ltltgtgt) defined for it.

A minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    std::bitset<120> b("01000000000000000000000000000000");
    std::cout << "initial value: " << b << '\n';

    b >>= 12;

    std::cout << "final value: "  << b << '\n';        
}
```

You can see the demo [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3364a2f7678cc86).

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best data structure to hold such a lengthy data?

Option 1:

```
struct MyType { uint8_t data[16]; };
```

Option 2:

```
struct MyType { uint16_t data[8]; };
```

Option 3:

```
struct MyType { uint32_t data[4]; };
```

Option 4:

```
struct MyType { uint64_t data[2]; };
```

Option 5:

```
struct MyType { std::bitset<128> data; };
```

It's hard telling which one will best serve you needs without knowing more about them.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason to avoid [`std::bitset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/)?

```
#include <bitset>
...
std::bitset<128> bs;
bs[0] = 1; bs[127] = 1;
std::cout << bs.to_string() << std::endl;
// prints 128 digits with ones on both ends
```